# How to work with C++ objects in JNA

Tags: java, c++, type-conversion, wrapper, jna

I am trying to access a C++ library from Java using JNA. To do so I have written a thin wrapper around the C++ methods that I require. However, wrapping the C++ object, passing to Java and back to C++ results in Invalid Memory access while accessing the object in C++. Any pointers on why this is happening will be very helpful.

**newencoder.h**

```
Class Encoder {

public:
Encoder();
~Encoder();

template<class Type>
bool originalEncode(Type* input);

}
```

**encoder_wrapper.h**

```
typedef void* EncoderWrap;

    extern "C" {
    EncoderWrap newEncoder();

    const char* encode(EncoderWrap vcEncoder);
    }
```

**encoder_wrapper.cpp**

```
#include "encoder_wrapper.h"
#include "newencoder.h"

EncoderWrap newEncoder() {
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(new Encoder());
}

const char* encode(EncoderWrap encoderObj) {
        std::string input;
        (reinterpret_cast<Encoder*>(encoderObj))->originalEncode(&input); //This is where the invalid memory access occurs. Commenting this line and returning a placeholder string does not throw any error.
        return input.c_str();
    }
```

**JNA**

```
private static class Encoder {

    public static native Pointer newEncoder();
    public static native String encode(Pointer encoderObj);

    static {
            Native.setProtected(true);
            Native.register("encoderlib");
    }

}

//Code that calls the native methods

Pointer encoderObj = Encoder.newEncoder(); //Does not fail
String result = Encoder.encode(encoderObj); //Results in Invalid Memory access
```

I tried calling the `encode()` method from within the C++ method `newEncoder()` and that works as expected. This memory error only happens when I receive the encoder object casted as void* in java and pass it back to the C++ method `enocode()`.

Comment: You _definitely_ can't return `std::string`, you need to return an allocated block of memory containing a C string (nominally std::string.c_str()) which will be guaranteed not to be freed until JNA has a chance to create a Java String based on its contents.

Comment: I'd recommend storing the object encoding on the object itself (even if it's regenerated on every call to `encode`) so that the memory doesn't get freed, then return a pointer to that string's C string buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by enclosing the void* in a structure and returning the structure to JNA. Every time the `newEncoder` is called, a structure instance is created which will have a new Encoder object casted as void* as a member.

The struct object is passed to the `encode` function every time. This method in turn casts the void* back to the object and calls the `originalEncode` method.

Answer (score 1):

As Vybz is suggesting, your problem is mixing C++ with JNA. JNA does not know about C++ structures and expects pure C.

In other words you can't assume a Java String is the same as a std::string. You can't use std::string in your interface.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem here. I changed the string to char* and error is still the same at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting a comment here, I don't have enough rep to properly post in the comment section.

I don't have much experience with java JNA stuff but in the C++ world

```
extern "C" {}
```

is used for making C++ code have C linkage. In encoder_wrapper.h you're using std::string which is a pure c++ construct. Have you tried removing the extern "C"?